# Swift 3: Playing Audio based on a string variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I see that the way to play audio in Swift 3 would be

```
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "name", ofType: "mp3")!))
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
catch {
print(error)
}
```

but instead of the set string of "name" I want to have a variable called **string** that could be one of 100 different strings corresponding to different filenames. Swift doesn't allow this by simply putting **string** in place of "name" so what's the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why this would not work:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
let string = "name"
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: string, ofType: "mp3") {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Anyways, calling your string variable string is probably not the best practice. Maybe you should rather call it "resource", "resourceName" or "fileName"?

Comment: weird. you're totally right. I'm not sure why i had trouble before, but thanks

Comment: @EmperorPalpatine You may have had trouble because the `AVAudioPlayer` was not retained.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a function like this, and pass in the name and the type of sound.

```
func playSound(name: String, type: String) {
    var Sound: AVAudioPlayer? = {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(name)", ofType: "\(type)")!)
        do {
            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: nil)
            return player
        }
        catch {return nil} } ()
}
```

Call it like

```
playSound(name: "The Sound", type: "mp4")
```

Hope this Helps! :)
Thumbs up if it does :D